# Proving that the preimage of a normal subgroup is a normal subgroup by showing equality of left and right cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism

This is Exercise 5 on page 60 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher.

**Exercise:**

> Let $\varphi \colon G \to G'$ be a homomorphism and $N'$ a normal subgroup of $G'$. Show that $\varphi^{-1}(N')$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

**Discussion:**

I found drhab's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/535419/homomorphism-and-normal-subgroups) and he shows that normality can be proven in about two lines. My question is whether this can be proven by showing equality of left and right cosets. My text (which is admittedly focused on analysis) defines a normal subgroup as one for which left and right cosets are equal. It does not discuss conjugation (is that the right word?) at all.

I found trying to prove that $g \odot \varphi^{-1}(N') = \varphi^{-1}(N') \odot g$ for $g \in G$ to be quite difficult. I had no idea how to use the normality of $N'$, which I assumed was necessary.

Does anyone know how to prove this using cosets? I appreciate any help.

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $g^{-1}$ on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that tries hard not to use anything equivalent to conjugates. (For the record, conjugates are definitely the way to go.)

The main idea is
$$g \odot \phi^{-1}(N') = \phi^{-1}(\phi(g) \odot N') = \phi^{-1}(N' \odot \phi(g)) = \phi^{-1}(N') \odot g.$$
The first and last equalities are sketchy and need justification. I'll do the first one since the second is the same.

For $x \in G$, we have
$$\begin{align*}x \in \phi^{-1}(\phi(g) \odot N')
  &\Leftrightarrow \phi(x) \in \phi(g) \odot N' \\
  &\Leftrightarrow \phi(g)^{-1} \odot \phi(x) \in N' \\
  &\Leftrightarrow \phi(g^{-1} \odot x) \in N' \\
  &\Leftrightarrow g^{-1} \odot x \in \phi^{-1}(N') \\
  &\Leftrightarrow x \in g \odot \phi^{-1}(N').
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I wrote a 'different' proof, thinking I'd got a simpler idea, then noticed that I'd essentially written exactly what you wrote. This is clearly the best way using just cosets.

Comment: @DavidACraven I tried for a bit to avoid inverses as well as conjugates, but I came to doubt the argument is true e.g. for monoids.

Comment: Wait, I didn't use inverses. I just set $N=\phi^{-1}(N')$, and then noted that $\phi(g\odot N)=\phi(g)\odot N'$, since $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven That's false. Take $\phi$ to send everything to the identity $e'$ of $G'$. Then your left-hand side is $\{e'\}$ while your right-hand side is $N'$.

Comment: Ok. Add 'we may assume wlog that $\phi$ is surjective' at the start. That assumes you know the intersection is normal in the image, but that's on your list of things to prove when doing this stuff anyway.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven As near as I can tell, actual proving the intersection is normal without resorting to conjugacy continues to require inverses. It's all a bit silly and pedantic, of course--I don't actually know of a weaker algebraic structure than groups where these manipulations would still be valid. How could something have inverses but no inner automorphisms?

Comment: I can see why people who want to get to a specific result in a lecture course on some other topic might introduce exactly what is needed. But how about $gN\cap H=g(N\cap H)$ (if $g\in H$)? This will need inverses but not conjugation.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Exactly what I had in mind. This whole exercise has convinced me that the closed-under-conjugation definition of normality is the conceptually correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Let $N:=\phi^{-1}N'$, that is $x\in N\iff \phi(x)\in N'$.

Then for any $g\in G$, $x\in N$, $$\phi(gx)=\phi(g)\phi(x)\in \phi(g)N'=N'\phi(g)$$ $$\therefore\phi(gx)=y\phi(g), \exists y\in N'$$

The question remains whether $y=\phi(x')$ with $x'\in N$. This is the case since $y=\phi(gx)\phi(g)^{-1}=\phi(gxg^{-1})$ so taking $x':=gxg^{-1}$ then $\phi(x')=y\in N'$ so $x'\in N$.